# TYPO3 6.2 fluid pagination not working as expected

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

My TYPO3 6.2 (Upgraded from TYPO3 4.5) fluid paginate displays all the items instead of 5 items.

My Repository Method :

```
public function getRandomLocation($iLimit)
{
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $result = $query->statement("Select * FROM      tx_sfel_domain_model_ttblocationsproduktegruppen WHERE hidden = 0 AND deleted = 0 AND logo != '' ORDER BY uid LIMIT 0, ".$iLimit." ");
    return $result->execute(); 
}
```

My controller code :

```
$aSResultsLocations = $this->tTBLocationsProdukteGruppenRepository->getRandomLocation($iLimit);
$this->view->assign('aSResultsLocations', $aSResultsLocations);
```

My template :

```html
    <f:widget.paginate objects="{aSResultsLocations}" as="aSResultsLocationss" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 5, insertAbove: 1 insertBelow: 1}"> 

                <f:for each="{aSResultsLocationss}" as="aSResultsLocation">
                     .................

                     //Getting all the items instead of 5 items.

                </f:for>
    </f:widget.paginate>
```

In `TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Widget\Controller\PaginateController.php indexaction()` I'm getting following results.

Code :

```
$itemsPerPage = (int)$this->configuration['itemsPerPage'];

$query = $this->objects->getQuery();
$query->setLimit($itemsPerPage);
if ($this->currentPage > 1) {
     $query->setOffset((int)($itemsPerPage * ($this->currentPage - 1)));
}
$modifiedObjects = $query->execute();
```

Values I got from here are :

$itemsPerPage : 5

```
$query : Select * FROM tx_sfel_domain_model_ttblocationsproduktegruppen WHERE hidden = 0 AND deleted = 0 AND (jahr = '13' OR jahr = '14' OR jahr = '15') AND logo != '' ORDER BY uid LIMIT 0, 26
```

$modifiedObjects count = 26

But I need '$modifiedObjects count' as 5.

I think Following are not working for my query object,

```
$query->setLimit($itemsPerPage);
$query->setOffset((int)($itemsPerPage * ($this->currentPage - 1)));
```

I think this issue is something related to my query object using in the paginate.
How to create query object for TYPO3 6.2 fluid paginate??

Please help me.

Comment: You cannot use a statement with paginate, because paginate will alter the orginal statement before being executed. It can only do this if it is a query create via query builder.

Comment: Thank you Pgampe. Your hint helps me a lot. I rebuilt my query using  query builder and ti's working now.

Comment: Hi all,

To fix the above issue i rebuilt the query in extbase query format. IN typo3 6.2.x paginate will not work with query statement so we need to convert it into extbase query format.

Comment: Please add your rebuilt query as answer instead of using a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the above issue i rebuilt the query in extbase query format. In typo3 6.2.x paginate will not work with query statement so we need to convert it into extbase query format.

My rebuilt query format is,

```
$constraints = array(); 
$subConstraints = array(); 
$query = $this->createQuery(); 

foreach($PublicationYears as $year) 
     $subConstraints[] = $query->equals('jahr', $year); 

$constraints[] = $query->logicalOr($subConstraints); 

$constraints[] = $query->logicalNot( $query->equals('logo', '') ); 

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints)); 

$query->setLimit((integer)$iLimit); 

$Result = $query->execute();
```